# Flutter Firestore QuerySnapshot has no instance of getter 'documentID'

Tags: flutter

I get an error that "QuerySnapshot that has no instance of getter 'documentID'".

```
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("CHAT").orderBy("createdAt",descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting)
        {
           return  Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator(color:Colors.green[300]));
        }
       else {
            var doc=snapshot.data!.docs;
            var user=FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
            return ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: doc.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx,index){
                 return BubbleMessage(
                   key: ValueKey(doc[index].documentID),
                   //:::::::::::::::get Message From firebase :::::::::::

                   message:doc[index]['message'],

                   //we check if the id isMe or the Other Person
                   isMe: doc[index]['userId']==user!.uid,

                   //::::::::::::::get  username From Firebase ::::::::::::::::::
                   username: doc[index]['username'],
 
          );
        },
             
     );
```

Why am I unable to access the documentID?

Answer (score 0):

The getter of the ID is just .id, not .documentID. [See here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#id). I'd recommend using your IDE's autocomplete to see what getters are available.

In the majority of cases the documentation on Flutter packages are extremely well documented and visible from within your IDE.

[image: Taken from my IDE]

Comment: how i use My IDE autocomplete.

Comment: I've tried many time but didn't show me if the getters are available.

Comment: @Oussamovic ctrl+space for autocomplete. Chances are if it doesnt show you the getters typical of a firebase querysnapshot then there is an error in your code and its not returning what you expect, the flutter extension is pretty smart and almost always right. rather than declaring 'var doc=snapshot.data!.docs;', give it the proper type 'QuerySnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs'. This way it will show you the correct ones, as type is not know with snapshots until runtime.

Comment: probably i have error in another place in the project.not in this case.